# how to LEFT JOIN a table where column's ids are in an $Array object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following array for `$table2Status`:

```
[{
    "Status_for_t2”:”2”,”id": "4"
}, {
    "Status_for_t2": "14",
    "id": "6"
}]
```

which is grabbed from `table2` which`has no index to`table1` but it requires to be a one to many relationship , the only thing they have in common is that
both tables are indexing status from another table.

I needed to somehow append columns from `table2`, I thought to add the `table2` id to my array so I could then
left join the `table2`  but I’m not sure how I should do it. I tried  this `ON  t1.status  IN ($t2_status)`  and this `ON  t1.status = 't2.status'` but obviously they are wrong, the query doesn’t scan the correct keys in
the array, it only populates the first index form my array. I feel like I should add something after `WHERE`.

What am I missing here?  what is the correct way to do this?  how do I bridge this two table?

```
function theResult ( $table2Status) {

    $t2_status = implode( ',', array_column( $table2Status, ’Status_for_t2’ ) );
    $t2_id= implode( ',', array_column( $table2Status, 'id' ) );
    //echo json_encode($theUserEvrIDs);

    $sql =
        "SELECT 
        
        t1.date,
        t1.status,
    
        t2.name_one,
        t2.name_two,
        t2.status
        
        FROM table1 as t1
        
        Left JOIN table2 as t2
        ON  t1.status  IN ($t2.status)      
    
    WHERE 
        t1.status IN ($t2_status)) 
        
    GROUP BY t1.id 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.status ) ORDER BY t1.date ASC";
    
    $result = $this->conn->query( $sql );

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        $returnArray[] = $row;

    return $returnArray;

}
```

Comment: `SELECT 

        t1.date,
        t1.status,

        t2.name_one,
        t2.name_two,
        t2.status .... GROUP BY t1.id` is invalid SQL  https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Show the schema of the two tables. You say there's no index, but there has to be some relationship between the two tables if you are going to join them What is the relationship?

Comment: Also, if the variable $t2_status is as shown, it will not be proper SQL syntax in the IN clause of your WHERE. Basically, as written, every row in t1 will match all rows in t2 where the in clause matches. Which will be no rows since the content of $t2_status is nonsense as far as SQL is concerned.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, I'm trying to understand your point. After I implode `t2_status`  I would get `(2,14)`, on the other hand In my `table1` I have the column `status` with the matching values.  so I use `WHERE  table1.status IN (2,14)`.

Comment: But that's an array, not a string. You would then need to implode it with a comma separator. The 2nd comment is that there isn't anything unique in your ON clause that expresses a relationship between t1 and t2.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, Yes I'm aware of the fact that my ON is wrong, so you saying I should maybe index table1.id in table.2?

Comment: No way of knowing. Post your table schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to see if there be a way to join a table using array but I guess there is not a less expensive/shortcut on that, so I ended up  creating a relationship by adding another column `T1_id` in table2 and getting table1.id indexed. Then I simply changed `ON  t1.status  IN ($t2.status)` to `ON  t2.T1_id = t1.id`.

It looks like it's working fine.